# Angular 2 share the same css file across the module

Tags: angular

It's possible to share the same css file across the same angular 2 module?

I know that I can set View Encapsulation Emulated to inherited parent component css but I want to share the same style across one particular module of my app.

This is my app structure:

- Main component

  - Module A (shared css style for this module)

    - Component 1
    - Component 2
  - Module B (shared css style for this module)

    - Component 1
    - Component 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. Simply create a file, `shared.scss` for example. Now you can import it in you components style: `@import './styles/shared.scss';` You could also add it to your `styleUrls` in your component.

Comment: I'm not sure but It seems this approach leads to css duplication for each of the components exporting it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491281/4572561
Does AOT compiler strip it?

Comment: Yes @DzmitryVasilevsky you are right, it would lead to duplication