# CSS is not working in my angular component

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to make a simple Angular4 web app that will show and X or O depending on what the rating is. I do not see the X or O in my web app.

The CSS classes in my rating.component.ts file are not working. My project is compiling because I can add text to my rating component template and it will show up on the webpage, but I cannot see the CSS that suppose to be rendered.

My app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <rating></rating>
     `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

My rating component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'rating', 
    template: `                   
        <i class="star" 
        [class.star-empty-icon]="rating < 1" 
        [class.star-full-icon]="rating >= 1" 
        (click)="onClick(1)">
        </i>
        <i class="star" 
        [class.star-empty-icon]="rating < 2" 
        [class.star-full-icon]="rating >= 2" 
        (click)="onClick(2)">
        </i>
    `
})
export class RatingComponent{ 
    rating = 0; 
    onClick(ratingValue){ 
        this.rating = ratingValue; 
    } 
}
```

My Css:

```
.star.star-full-icon{
    content:'X';
}
.star.star-empty-icon{
    content:'O';
}
```

Comment: yes! adding :before in the CSS worked. @serpent5

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I believe the problem you’re having is because you’re declaring the `styleUrls` on the parent component and due to encapsulation they are not available in the child component. You have to move it to the rating component.

In case you want to keep it on the level you currently have you need to make the view encapsulation none on the rating component.

```js
selector: 'rating',
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

I believe you also are misusing the content css property. You need to used either the `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements

```css
.star.star-full-icon::after{
    content:'X';
}
.star.star-empty-icon::after{
    content:'O';
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Still a blank page. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: But are the classes set on the elements?

Comment: Correct. I see this: <i _ngcontent-c0="" class="star star-empty-icon"></i>

Comment: And you did move the styleUrls to the ratings component, right?

Comment: Yes, it is in the rating.component.ts.

Comment: Can you try applying the start-empty-icon directly on the class instead of the class binding? To try and trace of it’s an issue with the evaluation of the expression. And can you try adding a different style like background colour or so to see if anything happens?

Comment: Okay. It has something to do with the <I> elements. I added a <div> to the template in ratings component with some styles defined in the same css file and the div's styles worked.

Comment: I believe you have to use the pseudo element ::before or ::after to set the content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: very interesting!

Answer (score 22):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

You need to add the CSS (`['./app.component.css'])` to `RatingComponent`, otherwise style encapsulation will prevent the CSS to be applied.

Alternatively, you can use `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep .star.star-full-icon{
    content:'X';
}
::ng-deep .star.star-empty-icon{
    content:'O';
}
```

or `ViewEncapsulation.None` on the `RatingComponent`

but I'd suggest to stick with the first option.

See also https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow

Comment: This did not work. Still a blank page. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: ng-deep is soon to be deprecated :)

Comment: No, it isn't. It will be remobed when all browsers work well with `Native` and `Emulated` is no lonher needed.

Comment: Have you checked the DOM if the classes are set as expected?

Comment: I get this: <i _ngcontent-c0="" class="star star-empty-icon"></i>

Comment: `_ng-content...` is added for style encapsulation. I'd check the added stylesand investigate why the selectors don't match.

Comment: Example should start with ::ng-deep (instead of :ng-deep). Double colon is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to mess with ViewEncapsulation and still have the styles isolation, [you can define the style within your global css file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542222/2780791) (e.g. styles.scss) by prefixing the component selector:

```
rating .star.star-full-icon{
    content:'X';
}
```

This was tested in an Angular 10 web application.