# CSS functions not working inside angular component

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

Hi all I am developing angular application in which if i use same HTML code inside index.html file its working as expected but if i use same HTML code inside app.component.html file i am not getting desired result.

**Expected Result**

[image: Image 1]

**Getting Result**

[image: image 2]

if I use below code it's not working.

```
<body id="top-page">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

but if i use HTML code inside body tag directly its working fine. Please help me find the solution.

Comment: Please, give more information about css styles on the page and 'app-root' component template.

Comment: I'm not changing any css in app component template same css as in index.html file css code is very long which I cannot include here

Comment: You can try to add `:host { display:block }` in 'app-root' component styles, but that's a blind attempt =)

Comment: Are 'easy payment' and 'first delivery' present on the page?

Comment: Actually I have multiple css files included in index.html file and only some css code are not working

Comment: You can try to reproduce the issue on stackblitz.com

Comment: ok I will create stackblitz and update you

Comment: You can try to check if css files are loaded correctly in network tool.

Comment: @MaxXx1313yes  'easy payment' and 'first delivery' present on same page

Comment: It's really a lot of possible reasons can be here =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239672/discussion-between-maxxx1313-and-chethan).

Answer (score 1):

Have you included your CSS file path in the index.html?
There might be a similar question here: [CSS is not working in my angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850510/css-is-not-working-in-my-angular-component)

Comment: Yes I had included css file path in index.html actually only some css functions not working