# how to style angular 4 component selector in global stylesheet?

Tags: angular, components, angular2-template

I need to add some style properties to my component selector in my global style sheet, but the added style doesn't affect the selector element in the browser.
how to accomplish this to affect the style on the component selector element.

my component file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-dashboardwidgets',
  templateUrl: './dashboardwidgets.component.html'
})
```

Mys stylesheet file

```
admin-dashboardwidgets {
   width: 100%;
   height:500px;
   background: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Why  do you want to use it in your global style sheet? You can use the :host combinator in your component's scss file directly

**dashboardwidgets.component.scss**

```
:host{
   width: 100%;
   height:500px;
   background: red;
}
```

**dashboardwidgets.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-dashboardwidgets',
  templateUrl: './dashboardwidgets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboardwidgets.component.scss']
})
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host

> Use the :host pseudo-class selector to target styles in the element that hosts the component (as opposed to targeting elements inside the component's template).

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the alternative of ng-deep like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843161/7099900) , so using this combinator is not really an option.

Answer (score 2):

By using class selector - you can achieve this.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: '.admin-dashboardwidgets', // class selector
   templateUrl: './dashboardwidgets.component.html',
   styles: [` .admin-dashboardwidgets{
     width: 100%;
     height:200px;
     background: red;
     }`],
     encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 })

<div class="admin-dashboardwidgets"></div> // HTML
```

Check the [live link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwwqh7?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a styleUrl to the component. It would be like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-dashboardwidgets',
  templateUrl: './dashboardwidgets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboardwidgets.component.scss']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global style applied for all components you have to create a stylesheet file and add it to the styles array in `.angular-cli.json`.

```
"styles": [
   "globalStyles.scss"
]
```

If you only want the style for one component you can add it to the components styleUrls array:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-dashboardwidgets',
  templateUrl: './dashboardwidgets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboardwidgets.component.scss']
})
```