# What is the long-term alternative solutions to /deep/ OR ::ng-deep?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, scss-mixins

/deep/ and ::ng-deep these are also deprecated in DOM mode and, i'ld like to know whether there will be an alternative in the future to /deep/ and ::ng-deep or should we start using other ways?

```
::ng-deep .result-container .options-section .option-radio-button .option-text p {
         margin: 5px 0px !important;
         white-space: pre-wrap !important;
     }
```

Comment: Look at css variables and constructable stylesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no alternative right now, so we should all continue to use it, because it's practical.

When `ViewEncapsulation.Native` is properly supported by all browsers and supports styling across shadow DOM boundaries, `::ng-deep` will probably be discontinued.

Comment: Native uses ShadowDom V0 which is deprecated.  Nobody should use it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for Angular projects at the moment, I use **ViewEncapsulation.None** as an argument in the **@Component** and the selectors arrive without using Shadow DOM.

e.g.:

```js
@Component ({
     selector: "app-onboarding-process",
     templateUrl: "./onboarding-process.page.html",
     styleUrls: ["./onboarding-process.page.scss"],
     encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```