# Apply style through DomSanitizer with class in Angular

Tags: angular

```
<div [innerHtml]="someHtml | safeHtml"></div>

someHtml = '<span class="fas fa-calendar" style="font-size:15px"></span>'
```

I inject a html element through `innerHtml` property and I could apply some inline-style by binding `DomSanitizer` pipe. But I wonder if there's any other ways to apply styles through `class` other than inline-style with `DomSanitizer`. After some research, I could make it work with `::ng-deep` but it seems deprecated according to the docs. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set styles for that dynamic html in a global style sheet, instead of in a component's stylesheet. You just have to make sure that you target that dynamic part only, so that your styles don't leak to other elements

**global.css**

```
my-component div.dynamicContentWrapper span .fa-calendar
{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div "class=dynamicContentWrapper" [innerHtml]="someHtml | safeHtml"></div>
```

***Using ng-deep***

`::ng-deep` is indeed tagged as deprecated in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), but it won't go away before there is any replacement found

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

[What to use in place of ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep)

**component.css**

```
:host ::ng-deep .fa-calendar {font-size: 15px; }
```

Comment: I haven't considered keeping the style of the dynamic html in the global style sheet! Thanks for sharing your insight :) Plus, I have also read their comments about `::ng-deep` and it doesn't seem to go away for a while but it will be gone eventually so I guess I won't go for it unless I have other option.

Answer (score 1):

You can always change your component encapsulation to `viewEncapsulation.None`.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]="safeHTML(someHtml)"></div>
  `,
  styles: [`.red { color: red }`],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  someHtml = '<span class="red" style="font-size:18px">Hello</span>'

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  safeHTML(str: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
  }

}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hftwuk)

Comment: AFAIK, `ViewEncapsulation.None` option might possibly mess up the style of application because it makes the style visible throughout the application. Because of this reason, I didn't want to take this option. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is correct. The styles will be applied globally. But by using `[innerHTML]` you are moving outside of the angular component architecture, so I don't think there is a way to keep the encapsulation.

Comment: You're right. I guess I've already broken sort of the encapsulation so setting ViewEncapsulation as none shouldn't be considered bad I guess.