# CSS style not taking effect

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief Explanation:** Due to some requirement, `HTML` code is written in `home.ts` and is loaded on `home.html`. `CSS` style is written in `home.ts` style component.

Problem: `CSS` style is not getting effected in the `HTML` code.

**`home.ts code:`**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styles:[`.p-tag{font-size:20px; color:red;}`]
})
export class HomePage {
code2='';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
// css .p-tag style is not effecting in below line on html page
   this.code2 = '<p class="p-tag">Html code From ts file.</p>';
  }

}
```

**`home.html code:`**

```
<ion-content>
    <div [innerHtml]="code2 | noSanitize"></div>
</ion-content>
```

For some reason we cannot call `css` from `.scss` file. We need to keep both `css` and `html` in ts as shown in above code.

Comment: See here if it  helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792898/1160794

Answer (score 1):

Use encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in @Component
Like as below

```js
import {ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styles:['home.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomePage {
code2='';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
// css .p-tag style is not effecting in below line on html page
   this.code2 = '<p class="p-tag">Html code From ts file.</p>';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Reference Link: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styles:['.p-tag{font-size:20px; color:red;}']
})
export class HomePage {
code2='';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
// css .p-tag style is not effecting in below line on html page
   this.code2 = '<p class="p-tag">Html code From ts file.</p>';
  }

}
```