# How can I apply custom CSS to a Toast with ng2-izitoast?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I want to apply a custom Style to the Toasts I show with izitoast in my Angular application.
I have installed and included the library according to instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-izitoast)
I have included the izitoast css and script in my angular.json in addition to  adding the module in my app-module and also managed to display a toast with a button in a component:

html-template (toaster.component.html)

```
<p>toaster works!</p>
<div><button (click)="produceToast()">Test Toast</button></div>
```

corresponding typescript file (toaster.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Ng2IzitoastService} from "ng2-izitoast";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toaster',
  templateUrl: './toaster.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toaster.component.scss']
})
export class ToasterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( public iziToast: Ng2IzitoastService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public produceToast() {
    this.iziToast.show({ title: "Hello World"});
  }

}
```

I understand that if I want to apply custom styling I have to somehow specify the class in the object I pass into the the `show()`-function, but how do I do that? Writing a CSS-class in my toaster.component.css and just referencing the name doesn't work:

```
.myOwnToastClass {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white; //font-color
}
```

Adding the class into my styles.css doesn't work either. Neither
`{class: "myOwnToastClass", title: "Hello World"}` nor `{class: ".myOwnToastClass", title: "Hello World"}` do anything.
Can someone tell me how to pass my own custom CSS to a toast? The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-izitoast) simply says "class: The class that will be applied to the toast. It may be used as a reference." but other than that there is no documentation on how to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Have you checked whether the class is added to the toast in your browser? Maybe the class gets added but the styles of that class are overwritten by something else.

Comment: The class doesn't get added to the toast nor to any created <div> of the toast. I checked.

Comment: It works for me, I tested it. There must be something wrong at your end. Could you copy paste your exact code in your question. Unfortunately I can't get ng2-izitoast working in stackblitz. Does everything else work except for adding `classes`?

Comment: Download this project and build it localy: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xio1zm This is working for me. (izitoast isn't working in stackblitz you have to download it and serve on your machine)

Comment: Yes it works. But the important part (pun intended) is the "!important" in your CSS, which frankly if I want to have multiple styles is pretty ugly. So it only works if I put my CSS in the styles.css and only if I add the !important modifier to it. And even then it doesn't work for everything. Although you can already change a lot of things around directly in the object you pass to the function.

Thanks for helping me though, it works now. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Btw, I think I oversaw the class in the produced div's. So I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so from the beginning ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So thanks to user fridoo I was able resolve it.

You have to add the class to your styles.css and be careful about the !important modifier:

```
.myOwnToastClass {
  background-color: blueviolet !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  //color: white; // you can't change the font-color with this
                  // you have to use the object-properties in the ts-file
}
```

Then reference it in the typescript files like so:

```
public produceToast() {
    this.iziToast.show({class: "myToastClass", title: "Hello World", timeout: 3000, titleColor: "#ffffff"});
        // titleColor: "white" would also work, I think it's a css-class somewhere in the background
  }
```

Comment: You have to use `!important` because you're overwritting existing styles. If you want to add your styles to the components css file instead of your global `styles.css` you could use `::ng-deep` before the css selector, e.g. `::ng-deep .myOwnToastClass { ... }`, but note that [ng-deep is deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). The styles won't apply otherwise because of [Angular's ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). You could [turn off ViewEncapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710912/9423231).