# blinkingtext is on all screens because of /deep/ - CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I implemented a blinkingtext animation on my system to keep blinking red, but I want it only on the screen that I am putting the code and not at all.
Follow the code below.

```
/deep/ nb-layout-header nav { 
    animation:blinkingText 1s infinite; 
}
@keyframes blinkingText {
    0% { 
        background-color: #374355; 
    } 
    100%{ 
        background-color: #D42333; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `/deep/` has been deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: @HereticMonkey what the alternative ?

Comment: It was a tough search, but I found [Alternative to /deep/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51708972/215552)... :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey even with the "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" continues with the same problem