# how to change ngb-pagination background color

Tags: angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I try to set background color to ngb-pagination item for angular2, but is does not work.

```
<ngb-pagination style="background-color:gray;" [collectionSize]="120" [(page)]="page" [maxSize]="5" [boundaryLinks]="true">
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know ng-bootstrap but as far I can see on their documentation page it's a component with list so you have ``ul`` element which contains ``li`` as items and those both have their classes so try to change their styles instead.

Comment: Thank you @Buczkowski for answer, I'll try it and write the result here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, thank for helping. In my condition problem solved like that in my css file. To overwrite the pagination stuff just using `/deep/` keyword.

```
/deep/ .pagination .page-item .page-link {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

/deep/ .pagination .page-link {
  border-top-style: none !important;
  border-bottom-style: none !important;
  background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work anymore. @ConnorsFan answer worked for me.

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated as of now. And even if ::ng-deep doesn'twork, visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep/49308475#49308475

Answer (score 10):

I don't if this library provide a way to customize the theme, if there that will be the best way.

But if you want to override some of the component inner styles you can use `::ng-deep`.

```
    ngb-pagination ::ng-deep ul > li:not(.active) > a {
          background-color: red !important;
    }

    ngb-pagination ::ng-deep ul > li.active > a {
          background-color: lightgreen !important;
    }
```

Also `style="background-color:gray;"` will definitely not work, you can see the DOM and it's style

Comment: You have to use `::ng-deep ngb-pagination ...` (change the order).

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party, but I got it to work in Angular 8 by adding the following code to my css file:

```
ngb-pagination ::ng-deep a {
  color: black !important;
}

ngb-pagination ::ng-deep .page-item.active .page-link {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

ngb-pagination ::ng-deep .page-item.active .page-link:focus, .page-link:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem dimgrey;
}

ngb-pagination ::ng-deep .page-link:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem dimgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggested answer didn't have any effect for me, `::ng-deep` selector looks like makes no effect to my page.

It worked with this:

```
ngb-pagination .page-item.active .page-link
    z-index: 3
    color: #fff   // text color
    background-color: #00AED6
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, the example below worked like a charm.

```
ngb-pagination .page-item.active .page-link {
  background-color: #7460ee;
  border-color: #7460ee;
}
```

Comment: tried this, but does not work without the `!important`