# Angular5 mat-menu modifying padding and width attributes?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Today I have this code, basically when I click on **Details** button it opens a `mat-menu` but somehow I can not modify padding or width values of the menu :

```
<div id="box-upload" [hidden]="hiddenBoxUpload" *ngIf="filesExist">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="listFiles">Details</button>
    <mat-menu class="filesList" #listFiles="matMenu">
        <div *ngFor="let key of listkey">
            <div *ngIf="detailsExist">
                <!-- some stuff like mat-progress-bar and span>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

css code :

```
.filesList {
   width: auto;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

What are the ways to change default padding and width of a `mat-menu` ?

Comment: Make sure your 'filesList' class is defined in your global style sheet.

Comment: Let's say I have myComponent.ts  and myComponent.html and myComponent.css, having 'filesList' in the myComponent.css file is not enough ? (of course in the .ts I have styleUrls: ['myComponent.css'] )

Comment: Yes - that's what I said - make sure your class is defined in the global style sheet. The overlay container (menus, dialogs, ...) is outside the DOM of the component, so the component's style is not applied.

Comment: Oh ok I thought you meant the style.css, I will try to directy add style inside then.

Comment: adding <mat-menu style="padding: 15px;  width: auto;"  ...>  didn't make it work

Comment: Global style = style.css - if that's your application's main style sheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either put the following in your global `styles.css`

```
.mat-menu-content {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Or you can use `::ng-deep` in your component style sheet

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-content {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Either solution above will allow you to modify the default padding of
   all mat-menu's in your project.

---

Per this SO answer, until an alternative or replacement is provided for ::ng-deep the recommendation is to continue using it...

[What to use in place of ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep/49308475)

---

If you want to control only a specific mat-menu you will need to use your custom class in your CSS selectors

```
::ng-deep .filesList .mat-menu-content{
    padding: 30px;
}
```

---

**Revision**

To adjust the width of the mat-menu without creating a scroll bar you need adjust the width of the root container `cdk-overlay-pane`... by adjusting the width of the `mat-menu-content` you are making that container wider than the root container, and because it is within the root container `cdk-overlay-pane` it creates a scroll bar by design. Try the following to widen the mat-menu without creating a scroll bar.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .filesList{
    min-width:600px;
}
```

Comment: And also for the width it works well, but there is alway a X scroll bar even with overflow: hidden !important; does there is anyway to hide the scroll until it reach the width I set?

Comment: I tried this with width of 600px : 
::ng-deep .listFiles .mat-menu-panel {
    max-width: 600px !important;
}
But it does not change the max-width parameter.

Comment: Please see revision on adjusting min-width to 600px on the root container without creating a scroll bar.