# Mat-datepicker-toggle showing behind modal

Tags: angular, calendar, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

Helloo,
I have a problem on my view using angular 4 and bootstrap 4. When I click on open to show calendar.
 It's showing behind my modal.
I want to change z-index on its class but i don't have acces to the class because it's auto-generated.
How can i fix the probleme?
[image]
This is my code.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that bootstrap-modal sets `z-index:1050`

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    outline: 0;
}
```

The material date picker sets `z-index: 1000` when the `ckd-overlay-pane` is created

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Adding this to your component style sheet should do the trick... but this will apply to all date-pickers in your entire project.

- You will need to include a custom class identifier to make this specific
  to your modal date-picker if you only want to change that one.

  ```
  ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container mat-datepicker-content{
    z-index:2000;
  }
  ```

---

Please reference the answer on this SO question for why using `::ng-deep` is ok until further notice.

[What to use in place of ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep/49308475)

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but still the same problem! :/

Comment: Hi @Marshal, it worked finaly by using ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container{
  z-index:2000;
}. thank u

Comment: When I added this. My hover tab that has z-index 1050 starts to flicker really fast.

Comment: This works for me as well ```::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index:2000;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your component style sheet

`.cdk-overlay-container { z-index: 1200 !important; }`

Comment: Does this answer add anything to Marshal's accepted one from 2018 or [Alex Guerreiro's 2020 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527964/mat-datepicker-toggle-showing-behind-modal/75533692#comment112012344_53528470)?