# Angular 6 Primeng confirmdialog inside of dialog deactivates page

Tags: css, angular, dialog, primeng, confirm-dialog

I am trying to add a confirm dialog into a dialog box that is in a component on my navbar.

```
  <p-menubar>
      <div>
          <app-overlay></app-overlay>
      </div>
  </p-menubar>
```

this component has an overlay Panel that opens a dialog box.  On the page that it is opening from also has a confirm dialog inside of it that is used for other reasons.  Whenever the overlay panel confirm dialog is opened, it opens the other graying out the screen and freezing the screen.  I have used the z index to bring the dialog forward but the background is still disabled after closing the dialog box.  I have also tried [appendTo]="body".  If I remove the confirmdialog on the back page then it behaves as normal.  So, I know it has something to do with having two, one opening the other.

Inside component that also has a confirmdialog box that opens when this is activated:

```
<p-dialog>
    <p-confirmDialog [appendTo]="body"></p-confirmDialog>
    <p-messages [(value)]="errors"></p-messages>
    <div>
    </div>
    <p-footer>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

Some css:

```
.ui-confirmdialog {
     z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

Nothing I tried has worked, so far any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW it is not good to use so big property(as `100000 `) to `z-index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the below to your component style sheet

```
::ng-deep .ui-confirmdialog {
  z-index:100000 !important
}
```

Without ::ng-deep it would need to go into your global style sheet.

---

Please reference the answer on this SO question for why using ::ng-deep is ok until further notice.

[What to use in place of ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep/49308475)

Answer (score 1):

Instead, Better to use same css in your global css (Style.css of root level)

```
body .ui-confirmdialog {
     z-index: 1001 !important;
}
```

But if you want to use css in your component level then you must need `ng-deep` as below -

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-confirmdialog {
    z-index: 1001 !important;
}
```

PS: BTW it is not good to use so big property(as 100000 ) to z-index.
(As per comment section)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but either one doesn't seem to solve the issue.  The back page is still grayed/disabled after closing modal when confirmdialog is activated on it.

Comment: @jason316 even I have tried the same, working on my local system. might be issue is somthing else

Comment: Yes works fine on a component that does not have a confirmdialog already on it but when there is two there seems to be a double layer of grayness that occurs and locks the page

Comment: Got it, the fix for me was to add a key attribute to the confirmdialog box so it knows which one to call, thanks everyone for the replys.

this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
      key: 'deleteConfirmation',
      header: 'Confirmation',
      accept: () => {
      },
      reject: () => {

      }
    });