# Angular Material UI TextArea Fill Height/Width

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using Angular v11 & [Angular Material Form field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples) how do I make a textarea mat-form-field take up entire space of container (not auto-grow as I type, but fill the space even if empty)?  It should be dynamic solution using CSS only, so as page is resized, so does the text field.

Here's [pic of actual page I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHaPx.png).  I tried to make sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-fill-test?file=src/app/app.component.html), however the Material UI doesn't even show properly there - can it?  Still hopefully it's helpful to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution finally that is fully dynamic without use of calc or any hard coded adjustments (notice you can add content in section above textarea and it resizes dynamically), see on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-fill-container?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.html).
One of the keys to making it work is this CSS, which I don't quiet understand:

```
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I did learn that the CSS above makes all elements' width/height account for border, padding as well, good explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing to those interested.

Comment: I don't know why this is  the accepted answer, it has no effect whatsoever related to the OP's question.
The correct answer (or at least one that works) is this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53621508/134120

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly your question you can just add this CSS in you `style.css` file. and add `fill-container` to the mat-form field element

```
.mat-form-field.fill-container,
.mat-form-field.fill-container .mat-form-field-infix,
.mat-form-field.fill-container .mat-form-field-flex,
.mat-form-field.fill-container .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-form-field.fill-container textarea {
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

**in temlplate**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="fill-container">
    <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput [matTextareaAutosize]="false"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

here is the stackblitz example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ms3ph?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.html

Also if you can use `matTextareaAutosize` instead of this style, I recommend usage of this `@Input` property

Like this

```
<div>
  
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="test">
    <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput [matTextareaAutosize]="true"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Comment: It already fills width.  I want it to fill height as well (height:100% doesn't work).  Also I want the nice Material format to remain intact.

Comment: @Ben I found a broken style, I have updated both(answer and example).

Comment: It didn't work for me.  Also on your stackbitz example it doesn't work -- try to type a lot, yo u'll see it goes past the text box... and also past the bottom of page.

Comment: @Ben please refresh the Stackblitz example I have fixed it.

Comment: It seems better now... but do you have solution without using calc() and hardcoded 25px?

Comment: @Ben it's ok, it's the margin and padding of the textarea element, you can leave it like that.

Comment: thanks for your help!! I found solution and posted here.  I used your sample as starting point so that Material UI displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a good idea to do this, but can give a try

```
<div #parent>

  <!-- ... other elements -->

  <mat-form-field class="textarea-mat-field">
     <mat-label>Text Content</mat-label>
     <textarea 
      matInput  
      placeholder="Enter document text..." 
      #newTextContent
      style="height: {{parent.offsetHeight - newTextContent.getBoundingClientRect().top}}px"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it dynamic.  As page resizes it should as well.  Prefer not to use any scripts, CSS only solution.