# How Can I customize mat-form-field in disabled state

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-7

I am trying to customize the angular material mat-form-field :
I was able to customize the underline border using :

```
::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

now I am trying to customize the underline border in the disabled state to be solid instead of the dashed line :

I tried this but it didn't work for underline :

```
::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled
 {

 }
```

[image]

I want this to be gray solid in disabled state

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input" [disabled]='true'>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi, how did you solve that?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912467/2727006

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This Fixed it :

```
 ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline 
    { 
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 33%, #c2c7cc 0 ) !important; 
    background-size: 1px 100% !important;
     background-repeat: repeat-x !important; 
    }
```

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated :') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the following class:-

`.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline`

The css you will be looking to change is:-

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.42) 33%,transparent 0);
background-size: 4px 100%;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

So you can either `unset: all` and start from fresh or update the `background-size: 1px 100%;` or whatever suits your needs

Comment: I tried it didn't work -->    ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled.mat-form-field-underline {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 33%,
    transparent 0
  );
  background-size: 4px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

Comment: Add it to your style.css without the ng-deep and you need to change the background-size. Also try adding !important.

Comment: Didn't work ---> .mat-form-field-disabled.mat-form-field-underline {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 33%,
    transparent 0
  ) !important;
  background-size: 4px 100% !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
}

Comment: Your background size is still 4px, also add a space between the classes.

Comment: This worked --> ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 33%,
    #c2c7cc 0
  ) !important;
  background-size: 1px 100% !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-disabled {
   .mat-input-element {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
    .mat-form-field-label {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
    .mat-form-field-underline {
         color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
    .mat-form-field-ripple {
         color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
    .mat-form-field-required-marker {
         color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it :

```
    ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 33%,
    #c2c7cc 0
  ) !important;
  background-size: 1px 100% !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need linear gradient in background-image. This worked for me:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: #949494 !important;
  background-size: 1px 100% !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-outline,
    .mat-input-element:disabled {
        color: red;

    }
```

this did the job for me, to color the text and the borders.