# how to change the color of icon in carousel?

Tags: css, angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I develop a function for **carousel**, I want to change the color of the icon **(next-icon and previous-icon)**, is it possible? and thnak's (i work with Angular 5)

file.html:

```
 <ngb-carousel [interval]="3000"> 
      <ng-template ngbSlide> ...  </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide> ...  </ng-template>
 </ngb-carousel>
```

_carousel.css:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: $carousel-control-icon-width;
  height: $carousel-control-icon-width;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: $carousel-control-prev-icon-bg;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: $carousel-control-next-icon-bg;
}
```

_variable.css:

```
$carousel-control-color:            $white !default;
$carousel-control-width:            15% !default;
$carousel-control-opacity:          .5 !default;

$carousel-indicator-width:          30px !default;
$carousel-indicator-height:         3px !default;
$carousel-indicator-spacer:         3px !default;
$carousel-indicator-active-bg:      $white !default;

$carousel-caption-width:            70% !default;
$carousel-caption-color:            $white !default;

$carousel-control-icon-width:       20px !default;

$carousel-control-prev-icon-bg:     str-replace(url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='#{$carousel-control-color}' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), "#", "%23") !default;
$carousel-control-next-icon-bg:     str-replace(url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='#{$carousel-control-color}' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), "#", "%23") !default;

$carousel-transition:               transform .6s ease !default;
```

Comment: If you are using ng-bootstrap's carousel, they are using an image for the icon. If you want to change the you will have to use another background image for `carousel-control-prev-icon` class

Comment: @Senal, i change background image in line **$carousel-control-prev-icon-bg** , i use :  str-replace(url("../../../img/icon.png), "#", "%23") !default;  . but the same don't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component.**
>   They are not inherited by any components nested within the template nor by any content projected into the component.

Since ngb-carousel is a nested component inside of your component, you have to include the css in your global css file.

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {

  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='#{$carousel-control-color}' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Or else you can use `::ng-deep` if you are adding styles from one of your component

```
::ng-deep .carousel-control-prev-icon {

  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='#{$carousel-control-color}' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Checkout this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edigw4?file=styles.css)

FYI, `::ng-deep` is deprecated but it's still there in angular. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep) out.