# Apply CSS class to component's child elements

Tags: css, angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following component's HTML ([StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-progress)):

```
<div class="measure">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="labelTemplate; context: templateContext"></ng-container>
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="state" [style.width.%]="progress">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="valueTemplate; context: templateContext"></ng-container>
</div>
```

And I am using it as follows:

```
<mk-progress class="test" [minimum]="0" [maximum]="100" [current]="40">
  <div *label class="label">Label</div>
  <div *value="let item" class="value">{{ item.progress }}%</div>
</mk-progress>
```

I need to apply css styles to `mk-progress` child elements when `mk.progress` has class `test`:

```
:host(.test) div.measure {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

:host(.test) div.label {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

:host(.test) div.value {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

The border is applied to measure but not to label and value. Why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `::ng-deep` shadow-piercing descendant combinator for that ([angular doc here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)):

```
:host(.test) ::ng-deep div.label {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

:host(.test) ::ng-deep div.value {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

This is a deprecated, but there is however no real substitute for it, see this [SO post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep).

> Long story short: Keep using ::ng-deep and its alternatives until a replacement is created - the deprecation is just an early notice so that people aren't blindsided whenever the actual change materializes.