# How to individually style Angular material components?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using two Angular material form components inside one component:

```html
<!-- First input -->
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text">
</mat-form-field>

<br>

<!-- Second input -->
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text">
</mat-form-field>
```

Before those input field are focused, they should look this

[image]

I need blue color for the first input mat-label when it is focused and label floats at the top left corner.

[image]

For second input mat-label, I want black color

[image]

Can anyone help me achieve this?
Many thanks

Comment: You can assign a class with `[NgClass]` to override the material style. Or, maybe, you can try out `[NgStyle]` but I believe that the ovverride required a `!important` at the end. Also, is up to you to add `/deep/` if you don't want those changes be reflected anywhere else

Comment: The labels in the both text fields should still show the 'black' color when they are not focused. Once focused, first one should show blue color and second one should show black color.

Comment: How about defining a mat-theme for that. You can define it globally or specific to a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the directive **::ng-deep** in CSS to style child component.

But in your context the **input** is part of your component so you can select it with `mat-form-field input[matInput] {}`

Comment: I have tried 
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
color : blue;
}

but it applies the styles globally for each form input field in the project. I need to apply the styles individually. 

I dont work to work with angular material theme as they are also applied globally

Comment: This is normal, add a class to your `mat-form-field` or your `input[matInput]` and select it, it should look like this : `::ng-deep mat-form-field.input-blue .mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label { color : blue; } `

Comment: `ng-deep` will be deprecated in future versions of Angular. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep

Comment: Keep using ::ng-deep and its alternatives until a replacement is created.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPaucot. Your suggestion worked with a slight change. 
::ng-deep .input-blue.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
  color : blue;
}

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid **::ng-deep**, you can apply styles in `styles.css`

```
  <mat-form-field class="">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <mat-form-field class="red-float">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
```

styles.css:

```
.red-float.mat-focused label{
  color:red !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7zyxo)

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

HTML

```
 <!-- First input -->
<mat-form-field class="first">
    <mat-label>Enter task 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text">
</mat-form-field>

<br>

<!-- Second input -->
<mat-form-field class="second">
    <mat-label>Enter task 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text">
</mat-form-field>
```

CSS

```
mat-form-field.mat-focused:first-child mat-label{
  color:rgb(0, 255, 55);
}


mat-form-field.mat-focused:last-child mat-label{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, tried that. It does not work. It changes the label text color when both text fields not focused.

Comment: updated my answer. Try this out. It should work now.

Comment: You can refer the example created by me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuhozs-64t4op?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.css

Comment: Thanks @Hardick, but I am looking to select by the class name here