# Angular + SCSS: how to apply style on component on parent :hover

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to show my component when it's parent is hovered.

The `action-list` component will display a list of possible actions when an element is hovered. The goal is to have a kind of contextual actions.

I am using `host-context` to detect the when a parent is hovered, but the issue is that will go through the parent tree.
If I'm have the following : `:host-context(:hover) {...}` the `action-list`will be shown as soon any of its ancestor (until body)are hover. In that case it will always be displayed [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4z5vwrn1j0)

I managed to make it work by setting a css class on the parent and in scss `:host-context(`.parent:hover) {...}` [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwjr24qq55)

It is working well, but I'd like to avoid having to set an extra class on the parent.

**QUESTION:**

**I know it is not possible in pure CSS, but is there an angular/scss magic syntax that will allow to select the direct parent?**

**Something like `:host-context(parent():hover) {...}`**

Answer (score 6):

Here is two solutions :

- In the parent component :

```
.parent-component:hover ::ng-deep app-child-component .div-in-child {}
```

- In the children component

```
:host-context(app-parent-component:hover) .child-component-div {}
```

**::ng-deep**  let you to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot accept it because:
1. ng-deep is deprecated : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles
2. the parent component can be any type of component (in your solution it will work only if the parent is an `app-parent-component`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep

It's actually deprecated but there is nothing to replace it. "Keep using ::ng-deep and its alternatives until a replacement is created - the deprecation is just an early notice so that people aren't blindsided whenever the actual change materializes."

What are you talking about "is an `app-parent-component` ?

Comment: In your 2nd solution: `:host-context(app-parent-component:hover) .child-component-div {}`, `app-parent-component` must be known by the child component, which I want to avoid. I would like to have a generic component.

Comment: Oh okay, i see.
The cleanest solution to do that is to work with an input with boolean (`@Input() showActions`) and in the parent.

And the other solution, not clean but more generic, is to get the component `constructor(element: ElementRef) {}` and accessing to the parent with `element.nativeElement`.