# Angular: override scss styles of nested component

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I created a spinner component.  I wanted it to be self-contained and not rely on external css, so in the component I include the scss to style it. The component template is a div with a class of `sbl-circ`.  I can add this anywhere in my app and it works as designed.

Now, I created a second component (a button). I want to add the spinner component to this button.  It works, but the spinner color is not correct for when it's inside the button.

So, I am trying to re-color the spinner with the scss for the button component.  So far the only way it works is if I do

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  button.btn.btn-primary {
    .sbl-circ {
      color: white;
    }
  }
}
```

I know that `::ng-deep` is deprecated.  What's the correct way for the button component to re-color any spinner components inserted inside of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep
Check that out for what to use instead of `::ng-deep`. My answer in that link works but I rather use your answer. Keep using `::ng-deep`, once deprecated, there will be a replacement. I think your solution is the best way.

Comment: not sure if it will solve the problem, but turning off view encapsulation on parent component might work

Comment: Could you provide the markup and/or the component architecture. Or possibly a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`:host-context`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context).

You should be able to use it like:

```
:host-context(button.btn.btn-primary) .sbl-circ {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my unfamiliarity with angular. But if I were to attempt the resulting css to not be over-written by another style, I would try to use `!important` as a property value in the scss.
Example:

```
p {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Depending on how Angular's ViewEncapsulation is set, that might not work.