# Edit shadow DOM in ionic 4 - ion-slides

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a ionic 4 slides component in which i want to change styling of the pagination bullets

```
<ion-slides class="lyt-carousel" pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

I'm able to change the color of the bullets by the below code(CODE #1) bt i want to add more customization like border-color,padding etc, which current I'm not able to do it (CODE #2)

CODE #1

```
.lyt-carousel {
  --bullet-background-active: red;
  --bullet-background: white;
  }
```

CODE #2

```
ion-slides {
  .swiper-pagination-bullets {

    margin-top: 15px;
    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
      border: 5px solid blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `::ng-deep` is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308475/11284140)

```
:host ::ng-deep .swiper-pagination-bullets {

  margin-top: 15px;

  .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    border: 5px solid blue;
  }
}
```

I would recommend a better way to implement you own style is setting it from the options. Here is the [API](https://swiperjs.com/api/#pagination) reference for further need

```
slideOpts = {
  initialSlide: 0,
  speed: 400,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    renderBullet: (index, className) => {
      return '<span style="border: 5px solid blue;"class="' + className + '"></span>';
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually no need of ::ng-deep as it is depricated. View Encapsulation is a property in angular using which i can achieve the expected result [link](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)  . Another website [link](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/) there they have explained the concept of shadow DOM and slots.

Comment: Yes.. I have attached a link to my comment which holds the same link you just shared. Anyway, I did point it out that I recommend that a better way to achieve this is by setting it from the `options`.