# Angular: ViewEncapsulation vs wrapping SCSS

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, angular2viewencapsulation

I find myself switching to ViewEncapsulation.None because I need to manipulate some child component's css, which does not seem possible with View encapsulation, as /deep/ was deprecated.

Are there any actual (performance perhaps?) drawbacks on using no ViewEncapsulation if my styles are manually scoped to the component? This seems to be able to manipulate the styles of child components correctly:

```
my-component {
  ... styles ...

  subcomponent {
    .gallery-item {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep/58081817#58081817

Comment: That basically just describes what I am doing, but does not answer the question on what drawbacks this approach has over using ViewEncapsulation