# How do I remove ws:nowrap from mat-slide-toggle in Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material

When using mat-slide-toggle, Angular Material adds a **white-space: no wrap** style(plus others) that I can't overwrite from the component scss file.

The style is added to both .mat-slide-toggle and .mat-slide-toggle-content. How can I overwrite those without going global?

Than you

Answer (score 0):

In your scss file

```css
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-slide-toggle {
      white-space: normal !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't ng-deep being removed? Will there be an alternative?

Comment: @orbitory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep Accepted answer. I've been searching for a replacement too, but sadly it doesn't exist. I read about something similar called `slotted`, it's not yet available though

Answer (score 0):

This work for me (angular 11)

```html
::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-content {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```