# How to change styles of child mat angular component?

Tags: css, angular, styles, ng-deep

As angular official documentation says, `::ng-deep , >>>, /deep/` is deprecated and will be removed soon:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

If i am using `mat` components like `<mat-checkbox>` or a more comprehensive one like `<mat-table>` how could I have some changes to that component from parent?

1. Should I cancel view encapsulation for that component and write
   styles in `.SCSS` files?
2. How do I edit styles of `inner` material angular component if **deep selector** is going to be removed?
3. What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the mention document says you can use the combination of `::ng-deep` with `:host` and it will be OK in this way.

> In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include the `:host` selector before `::ng-deep`. If the `::ng-deep` combinator is used without the `:host` pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into other components

```css
:host /deep/ h3 {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

But, you also can use the custom `CSS` **class** & **id** to apply your custom css on `.CSS` or `.SCSS` files on the **Angular Material Components**. using `.class` & `#id` in combination with `mat` default classes works.
In addition you can use custom Angular material classes in your componnent style files ( `.CSS` or `.SCSS`) to override the like this:

```css
.app-component-style {
/* All the CSS here */
.mat-tab-group .mat-tab-label {color: green;}
}
```

So, keep using it as **Dudewad** mention here too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308475/4185370

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Going to read and try that out in a moment. So, ::ng-deep with :host won't be deprecated ? I worry only about that

Comment: `::ng-deep`  with `:host` won't disturb template encapsulation, So it's ok to use. Since there is no alternative right now, it's ok. Use it and don't worry.