# angular - override mat-form-field inherited styles

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using `ViewEncapsulation.None` to override the material styles of my custom mat-form-field component that I use in my login page. However, I have reached a scenario where down the line in the app, whenever I use another `mat-form-field` in another component, some styles that are used in the login page mat-form-field are inherited, leaving the current component styles with no effect.

You can see what I mean below. This is the first instance where I use the first `mat-form-field`:

[image]

But when I use a `mat-form-field` again, in another component, some styles are ignored, like so:

[image]

When in reality, this would be the desired result:

[image]

What can I do to override these inherited styles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your styles to only apply to the custom field, rather than any direct usages of mat-form-field.

You can set up your custom field with normal view encapsulation (as long as you aren't using the shadow-dom)

Then you use `::ng-deep` to pierce the encapsulation.

For example one method I often use for selectors that don't select anything rendered by the component itself (ones that won't have the hash code attribute for the view encapsulation) is to select the `:host` element and then do a descendant combinator from there with `::ng-deep`.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
 background: pink;
}
```

Note, you might need to play around with things a little and double check which styles are/aren't getting applied via the dev tools.

---

## Background Information

[`:host`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) selects the host element. This element is what angular automatically creates as the parent of all components. It'll be kebob case component name and would be selectable via `:host` which gets the current component's host element (via attribute selector), or it can generally be selected via `component-name {}` as if it is a normal element.

The host element is what classes and inline styles get applied to, because Angular knows they are always there. There is also no way to avoid having a host element in Angular (there was a way back in angular.js)

[`::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) as mentioned is "deprecated". The problem is... [there's no replacement for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep). Working with other libraries while trying to encapsulate some changes, it's easy enough to keep using ng-deep. Google has never given a removal version for it despite being "deprecated", and there have been several major versions since that deprecation. From an [Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21511), it looks like they don't plan to remove ng-deep until there's a replacement.

That being said, if you really don't want to use ng-deep, then you can remove ViewEncapsulation and replace the `:host ::ng-deep` by selecting the host element yourself via the host element's element selector. For example, `component-name .mat-form-field{}` will select `.mat-form-field` class only when a child of the host element `component-name`.

Comment: That seemed to solved my problem. I was aware of `ng::deep` but was a little hesitant on using it since it is deprecated but the frustrations of using `ViewEncapsulation.None` might just ecplise the worry of using a deprecated combinator. Btw, I don't really understand the `:host` part, could you explain? Should I always use it with `::ng-deep`?

Comment: @ManuelBrás, hopefully this answers all your questions!

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! `::ng-deep` seems to make my life easier right now. Also, is there a way I can group all the material styles I'm using under a single `::ng-deep`? Would be cleaner that way, if possible.

Comment: I believe that using scss/less, you can use nested classes and it'll work fine. `:host ::ng-deep{ .mat-form-field:{ } }` should work in theory.

Comment: I can't get this to work the other way around (status form to login form) though. The login form field won't have the correct styles. This is pissing me off.

Comment: Try passing in a relevant class to the mat form field, and using those to style off of instead of the more generic MUI classes. That way you are using completely different classes as a base between the login form and the status form.

Comment: Could you give an example? I tried this before but didn't manage to get it working, must have done something wrong for sure.

Comment: Here's an example of setting a class on the MUI components, and then styling off of those without bleeding via ViewEncapsulation.None: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwcqgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-theming-example.css
 Obviously you'll have to be careful whenever you use ViewEncapsulation.None.