# How to style :host based on direct parent?

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

I've got a custom component `<ui-title>` that I wish to style differently based on what its direct parent element is.

For example, if it appears within `<ui-section>`, style it YELLOW.  Within `<ui-card>` style it BLUE.  If it appears anywhere else, style it GREEN.

Here's what I've tried:

```css
:host {
  background-color: green;
}

:host-context(ui-card) {
  background-color: blue;
}

:host-context(ui-section) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

This doesn't work because if an element is nested within both `<ui-section>` and `<ui-card>` because both sets of styles would be applied.  I wish to apply a set of styles based strictly on the direct parent of the :host element.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u9xt3h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fui-title%2Fui-title.component.css) that shows my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can combine `:host` and `::ng-deep` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542222) after few hours of searching and trying different combination of `::ng-deep`, `:host` and `:host-context`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yf1uff?file=src/app/ui-title/ui-title.component.css

So just moved the style related to the `ui-card` and `ui-section` to their own stylesheet and combine `:host` and `::ng-deep` with child selector `>`

### ui-card.component.css

```scss
:host > ::ng-deep ui-title {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

### ui-section.component.css

```scss
:host > ::ng-deep ui-title {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

### ui-title.component.css

```scss
:host {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You have to test on Safari and Firefox, For instance; ``host-context`` is a Chromium only party

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, my answer does not use any `host-context`